# How to get $END$ to be replaced by cursor in PHP Storm Live Templates

Tags: phpstorm, live-templates

I created a live template in PHP Storm:

```
// $date$: $END$;
```

which I understand should print the date, and then put the cursor in the place of $END$.

However, when I type the abbreviation and press TAB, it highlights the date:

[image]

How can I get the cursor to be waiting in front of the semicolon?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you open the "Edit variables" dialog, check the "skip if defined" checkbox to skip editing the $date$ variable.